# robot_localization using UKF have some problem

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I using Ububtu 14.04 and ros-indigo-devel for robot_localization

This my ukf.yaml

> 

frequency: 30
sensor_timeout: 0.1
transform_time_offset: 0.0
two_d_mode: true
print_diagnostics: true
map_frame: map
odom_frame: odom
base_link_frame: base_link
world_frame: odom
alpha: 0.001
kappa: 0
beta: 2
odom0: /odom
odom0_config: [false,false,false,
false, false, false,
true, false, false,
false, false, false,
false, false, false]
odom0_differential: false
odom0_relative: false
odom0_queue_size: 50
odom0_nodelay: false

I confirm the position.z is zero in /odom messages.

I start 2d pose estimate using ukf and pose_z is non-zero value.

I try track it and find out when computing sigma point , the position.z provide non-zero value.
`sigmaPoints_[sigmaInd + 1] = transferFunction_ * (state_ + weightedCovarSqrt_.col(sigmaInd));` in ukf.cpp

Is it OK ?

By the way , I using EKF to estimate pose and position.z is always zero.

Sample input is from odom

[image description http://blackdragonyu.no-ip.org/web_images/2016-10-24_181611.png](http://blackdragonyu.no-ip.org/web_images/2016-10-24_181611.png)

The attachments are my UKF and EKF yaml

http://gofile.me/2jhbn/ZEJnxxcKD

The output please see these images:

### [image description http://blackdragonyu.no-ip.org/web_images/2016-10-24_191341.png](http://blackdragonyu.no-ip.org/web_images/2016-10-24_191341.png)

---

[image description http://blackdragonyu.no-ip.org/web_images/2016-10-24_191433.png](http://blackdragonyu.no-ip.org/web_images/2016-10-24_191433.png)

Update 1 :

The following is my log. Please reference

1. When starting UKF localization , I found create sigma points that just provide non-zero for z-position of robot's pose
   [image description http://blackdragonyu.no-ip.org/web_images/ukf2.png](http://blackdragonyu.no-ip.org/web_images/ukf2.png)
2. Because all sigma point are not zero , the z-position of robot's pose is not zero also.
   [image description http://blackdragonyu.no-ip.org/web_images/ukf.png](http://blackdragonyu.no-ip.org/web_images/ukf.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245981/robot_localization-using-ukf-have-some-problem/) by [sai5555](https://answers.ros.org/users/28288/sai5555/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-10-24**:
Can you please clean up the .yaml printout and also post sample inputs from every message? Thank you.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-10-24**:
Also, have you tried using the EKF to see if it behaves the same way?

**Comment by [sai5555](https://answers.ros.org/users/28288/sai5555/) on 2016-10-24**:
Yes , I tried EKF using same yaml and EKF  dont have this problem

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-11-01**:
`1e-18` is effectively 0. Does it ever become larger, or does it stay around there?

**Comment by [sai5555](https://answers.ros.org/users/28288/sai5555/) on 2016-11-07**:
About le-18~le-20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The UKF has a prediction and correction step. The prediction step uses the sigma points to project the state forward. The sigma points are based on the state's covariance matrix, and the `Z` value will never be exactly 0 (in fact, it can't be). Note that this differs from the EKF, which projects the state forward using only the motion model. When you see non-zero values from the UKF, it may be due to a cycle that had a prediction step with no correction.

However, please note that the Z values you are posting **are effectively 0**. In the example you posted above, `3.87298e-06` is `0.00000387298`. If your system is sensitive to that level of error, you may want to stick with the EKF.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai5555](https://answers.ros.org/users/28288/sai5555/) on 2016-11-10**:
OK , so it is normal ?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-11-10**:
Yes. I was explaining how the UKF works to make it clear why you're seeing the values.